# i2djs set attribute {d} to a variable

Tags: javascript, path

I am trying to create a project where I need to be able to change what is inside an input tag and the program will create an animation where the letter or number you put in . It Will be displayed for example if you put the lowercase letter
"B" the code would be

> `M20,36 v-32 v14 a2.6,2 1 0 1 2,16`

here is what I have
answers1 is my variable I need in  attr: d

```
var nodes = renderer.createEls(answers1, { 
   el: "path",
   attr: {
      d: 'M0,20  l10,16 l10,-16',  
   },
   style: {
      lineWidth: 5,
      strokeStyle: "#f00000",
      shadowColor: "red",
      lineCap: "round",
   },
}).animatePathTo({
   duration: 100,
   loop: 1,
   ease: "linear",
   direction: "alternate",
});
```

I feel the answer is incredibly simple but I am unable to find it out for the last five hours.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get an attribute `d`  from the variable `answers1` and use it in the other object?

Comment: sorry If I miswritten it . In the variable nodes there is the d attribute .  I would want answer1 to be used in the variable nodes  where 'M0,20  l10,16 l10,-16' is I want it to be replaced with answer1 which
answer1 is currently 'M20,36 v-32 v14 a2.6,2 1 0 1 2,16'

Answer (score 0):

create the path node, and keep the reference of it. Then use the reference to animate as well as to change the path.

```js
var pathNode = renderer.createEl({ 
   el: "path",
   attr: {
       d: 'M0,20  l10,16 l10,-16',  
   },
   style: {
      lineWidth: 5,
      strokeStyle: "#f00000",
      shadowColor: "red",
      lineCap: "round",
   },
})

# animate Path
pathNode.animatePathTo({
   duration: 100,
   loop: 1,
   ease: "linear",
   direction: "alternate",
});

# Change Path
pathNode.setAttr("d", 'M20,36 v-32 v14 a2.6,2 1 0 1 2,16' )
```